# Run browserify upon file change with tsc -w

Tags: npm, browserify, tsc, lite-server

I am new to npm build tools. I want to bundle the compiled typescript files as soon as there is a change in typescript files and run lite-server concurrently. To achieve that I have written following npm build script -

```
"build": "tsc",
"bundle": "browserify -s main app/goc-common/common.module.js > dist/bundle.js", 
"build_dev": "npm run build && npm run bundle && concurrently \"tsc -w && npm run bundle\" \"lite-server\"",
```

However this doesn't seems to work, it just compiles the files and refresh the browser, donot bundle the files again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `watchify` to continue watching `tsc`'s output files for changes:

```
"build": "tsc",
"bundle": "watchify -s main app/goc-common/common.module.js -o dist/bundle.js",
"build_dev": "npm run build && npm run bundle && concurrently \"tsc -w && npm run bundle\" \"lite-server\""
```

As you've noticed, `browserify` doesn't watch; it just runs once and then it's done. [`watchify`](https://github.com/substack/watchify#usage)'s usage is identical to `browserify`'s, except that the `-o` option is mandatory.